# Anchor tag display full link issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, tags

I found some really awesome link detection regex that works unbelievably great. It takes only the main part of a link and displays it as the body of the anchor tag and the whole link as the href. In example `http://somesite.com/index.php?some=var` will simply look like `somesite.com`. Which is just pure awesomeness, but then again it has its down side as well because someone might pass some variables that you might not necessarily want to send for some reason and I figured I need to display the whole url in the anchor body. Sadly I don't want to just give up on beautiful anchors and I decided I should display full link upon some event and thus came the trouble.

First I thought I should go for mouse hover (jquery's mouseenter) to display full link and then use mouseleave to make it beautiful again. Unfortunately that was unsuccessful due to short site names at the end of a line with a bunch of parameters. Example: If there is an anchor with body `site.com` and href `http://site.com/some/params` at the end of a line, after expanding it will go to the next line which would trigger the mouse leave and thus compressing it, which would by it self return the link to the original line and trigger the expand function creating an infinite loop.

Second idea was to have a right-click expand the link. Obviously the context menu on links that are to be expanded has to be disabled. Unfortunately, again, having the same link at the end of a line would cause a context menu to show up because after expanding the right click is also triggered at the blank space where the short link used to be.

I seem to have run out of ideas, does anyone have any?

Comment: It's not enough to have the full link displayed in the status bar on hover (standard behaviour for all the browsers I use).

Comment: I'd do it SO-style, hide `http://www.` and leave the rest visible. No usability issues and no JS required.

Comment: @nnnnnn There are users that don't even know what that is, and they are not a few. I suppose that expanding links wouldn't matter to these users as well but oh well... That is a good idea for an excuse if I need one though, haven't thought of that, thanks! :P

Comment: @FabrícioMatté There are a lot of sites that do not use seo friendly urls and I don't want to display those parameters at the end :s

Comment: Well, as you've said, there are users that don't even know the status bar so expanding links would probably be much worse for them imho. `:P` I've thought about some CSS hackery. This will prevent links from wrapping http://jsfiddle.net/yp7hr/1/ but then you have a broken layout. It is probably better to put a tooltip (as the native `title` attribute) showing the full URL to don't break the layout.

Comment: titles are an awesome idea! How could I not think of that, God! Thanks! :P You might as well answer that ^.^

Comment: @php_nub_qq it's tough to give a good solution to this problem without knowing your html/css

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, you have an answer invitation :)

Comment: @Sergio thanks for the notification. `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without breaking layout, you can use the native [`title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.title) property to display the full URL or, for something more customizable, a plugin such as jQuery UI's [tooltip widget](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

```
<a href="http://www.shorturl.com/?param=notSoShortUrl"
  title="http://www.shorturl.com/?param=notSoShortUrl">shorturl.com</a>
```

Provided the `title` attribute is outputted in the initial markup, this solution works even with JS disabled. And if you feel like, jQuery UI tooltip may help customizing it for JS-enabled users.

---

If anyone is interested in how to patch the line-breaking issue described in the OP, here's my original solution to achieve non-line-breaking extensible links:

```
<a href="http://www.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com/?params=somelongstring">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com</a>
```

```
$('a').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).text(e.type == 'mouseenter' ? this.href : $(this).data('shorturl'));
}).each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        width: this.offsetWidth,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        display: 'inline-block'
    }).data('shorturl', $(this).text());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yp7hr/2/)

Though, this is mostly a CSS hack and link text may leak outside of the container (and obviously, won't work if the container has `overflow:hidden`), so it is not very good for layout purposes. Better stick with `title` or the tooltip plugin.